# Open file in new window after searching it with helm

Tags: helm, window, files, helm-for-files

As written in [A Package in a league of its own: Helm](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html#sec-2) there's a way to

1. search for a file using `Helm`
2. decide after searching whether open it in *same* or *other window*

My question is: How?

Comment: If you keep reading the guide, you will see that it tells you use `RET` to open file in current window and `C-c o` to open file in other window.

Comment: Use `TAB` (`helm-select-action`) to open action menu and choose one you want, in your example: "Find file other window" or "Goto line other window" etc, you can also just use shortcuts (usually bind to `C-c o`) like Tu Do said.

Comment: @xuchunyang I don't know what you mean or how to do it. Here is what I tried: found file using `helm-find-files` (that's `C-x C-f` for me) after this pressing `TAB` creates buffer with that file. Pressing `TAB` again kills it. How should i do `helm-select-action`?

Comment: @Empty_Mind In helm, `TAB` is binded to `helm-select-action` by default, if you change it by yourself you should know that.

Answer (score 18):

I'm using Spacemacs (on Windows 10 if that matters) with the default keybindings. This may differ from your configuration, but I found the following ways to open files via Helm-Find-Files:

- Open Helm-Find-Files - <kbd>SPC</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>
- Type in filename (via tab completion etc.). Once file has been selected, there are 3 options I use for opening the file:

  - Option 1. <kbd>Tab</kbd> to preview file and <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to close the preview (stays in Helm-Find-Files)
  - Option 2. <kbd>Return/Enter</kbd> opens the file in the same window that I was in before calling Helm-Find-Files
  - Option 3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> opens the file in another window.

Comment: How would you open in a **vertical** window?

Comment: I'm not sure @fraxture. I don't have spacemacs installed anymore either (switched jobs a while back and never got around to setting it up again).

Comment: The `Ctrl + c o` is actually working for me as I set the default for emacs to open in a vertical split. Funnily, the tab option doesn't work I get a message saying "Cannot split side side window or parent of side window."