# helm-ag (or equivalent) open selection in existing window?

Tags: buffers, helm, window, projectile, ag

If you run `helm-ag` (I typically do this with `helm-projectile-ag`, but I think it should be similar) and select a match, the file / buffer opens in the last used window.

My question is this: If a you already have the file / buffer open in an existing window, can you force the match to open in *that* window? This keeps the position of files in your frame more stable.

There's a similar question here: [Open file in a specific window](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17072/open-file-in-a-specific-window), but I figured this would be a common (and perhaps solved) use-case. If not, maybe I could override the action initiated on `RET` to scan my existing windows and, if a window has the right buffer already open, open it there? I'm not sure if there's a better way to do it.

Thanks for any help!