# Can't use helm `find-file` action with key binding

Tags: key-bindings, helm

I have the following code that I found [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17072/open-file-in-a-specific-window) (note that the buffer version works fine):

```
(use-package helm)
(use-package ace-window)

(defun helm-find-ace-window (file)
  "Use ‘ace-window' to select a window to display FILE."
  (ace-select-window)
  (find-file file))

(add-to-list 'helm-find-files-actions
             '("Find File in Ace window" . helm-find-ace-window)
             :append)

(defun helm-file-run-ace-window ()
  (interactive)
  (with-helm-alive-p
    (helm-exit-and-execute-action 'helm-file-ace-window)))

(define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "M-o") #'helm-file-run-ace-window)
```

If I run `helm-find-files` and then hit TAB on a file (to open the action menu), I am able to scroll down to an entry called `Find File in Ace window` and hit enter. This works perfect.

Strangely though if instead of hitting TAB I use my `M-o` key binding, emacs spits back to me: `[No such action 'helm-file-ace-window' for this source]`.

I find it contradictory that I can select the action from the action menu, yet when I use a key binding emacs says the action does not exist.

I am using Emacs 27.2 and Helm 3.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `helm-file-ace-window` to `helm-find-ace-window`.